# How often I can use USR1 for nginx?

Tags: nginx

How  often I can use USR1 for nginx ? For example if I want rotate logs every minute - is it affect to productivity of nginx server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small amount of overhead in reloading the log files. If you have concerns about the performance of the operation, I recommend you test with your own application to confirm it will work fine in production for you. You can observe the memory and and CPU use during repeated use of the USR1 signal, and well as benchmarking the request volume you can handle with and without the rotation happening.